# How to communicate between 2 qml windows

Tags: qt, qml

I have some questions regarding QML. I have a TableView and , when i click on a column header, i need to open a new window which contains all elements under that column with a button on the left of each element. 
Clicking on that button should send a message back to TableView to update.
My questions are:

- How can I catch the mouse click for a column?
- Which would be best solution for the 2nd window: a tableview with 2 columns(one for the button and one for the element)? In this case I am not sure how to set the value for the 1st column...
- How can i pass messages between 2 qml windows?From the 1st window i send the model(elements under the column) and from the 2nd windows i send back one or multiple values(depending on how many buttons are checked)
  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can communicate inbetween multiple windows in QML, just the the same way, as you communicate between any other two `Items` by referencing them via `id`s or assiging them to properties that you later use to reference them.
An examople:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

Item {
    ApplicationWindow
    {
        id: appWindow
        width: 500
        height: 800
        visible: true

        ListModel {
            id: lm
            Component.onCompleted: {
                for (var i = 0; i < 42; i++) append( { message: 'Hellow World ' + i })
            }
        }

        ListView {
            id: lv
            width: 300
            height: 800
            model: lm
            delegate: Button {
                text: model.message
                onClicked: secondWindow.text = text
            }
        }
    }

    ApplicationWindow
    {
        id: secondWindow
        width: 500
        height: 800
        x: appWindow.x + 500
        y: appWindow.y
        visible: true
        property alias text: label.text

        Text {
            id: label
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }
}
```